# I/O addEventListener does not start

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, addeventlistener

On my page, I have an input field that accepts an integer-input and the JavaScript function calculates the values and outputs in 2 different other boxes. This is a basic "Fizz Buzz" I/O project.

I built everything around the exact code (JS) and architecture (HTML) from another project that works fine. In this code, however, entering the integer does not start any calculations. Also the console.logs() are never written. My code is provided below...

```js
var init = 0;

document.getElementById("intArr").addEventListener('input',
function(e) {
    init = e.target.value;

    var arr = new Array(init);

    for (i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {

        arr[i] = i + 1;

        if (arr[i] % 3 === 0) {
            console.log('Fizz' + arr[i]);
            // document.getElementById('Fizz').innerHTML=arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] % 5 === 0) {
            console.log('Buzz' + arr[i]);
            // document.getElementById('Buzz').innerHTML=arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] % 3 === 0 && arr[i] % 5 === 0) {
            console.log('Fizz-Buzz' + arr[i]);
            // 
            document.getElementById('fizzBuzz').innerHTML = arr[i];
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="intArr" type="number" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Enter Integer for Array">
    </div>
</form>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fizz</label>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div id="Fizz"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Buzz</label>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div id="Buzz"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fizz-Buzz</label>

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div id="fizzBuzz"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please provide more info above -- what's the error message, or what are you expecting to happen that is not?

Comment: Errors? console logs? indication of failure? It does not _**seem**_ to work? Is there a question you would like to ask?

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using a loop here? Do you want to print Fizz, buzz or Fizzbuzz for the values 1-7 if you enter 7 in the box? Or just for the value 7?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the entered value to number.

Look what happens to the attribute `length` when you're passing a string and a number:

```js
var arr = new Array("5");
console.log(arr.length)

arr = new Array(5);
console.log(arr.length)
```

**An alternative is:**

```
var arr = new Array(+init);
                    ^
```

```js
var init = 0;

document.getElementById("intArr").addEventListener('input',
  function(e) {
    init = e.target.value;

    var arr = new Array(+init);

    for (i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {

      arr[i] = i + 1;

      if (arr[i] % 3 === 0) {
        console.log('Fizz' + arr[i]);
        // document.getElementById('Fizz').innerHTML=arr[i];
      }
      if (arr[i] % 5 === 0) {
        console.log('Buzz' + arr[i]);
        // document.getElementById('Buzz').innerHTML=arr[i];
      }
      if (arr[i] % 3 === 0 && arr[i] % 5 === 0) {
        console.log('Fizz-Buzz' + arr[i]);
        // 
        document.getElementById('fizzBuzz').innerHTML = arr[i];
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="intArr" type="number" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Enter Integer for Array">
  </div>
</form>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fizz</label>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div id="Fizz"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Buzz</label>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div id="Buzz"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fizz-Buzz</label>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div id="fizzBuzz"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The "alternative" returned output. Instead of "init = this.value;" I used "init = e.target.value" and that did not visibly change anything. I still don't understand why "+init" is needed. To my understanding "init = e.target.value", initializes "init" as integer OR is "+init" related to "this.value" and "e.target.value", respectively?

Comment: @iBim'sdaMichi the first time `init = 0` is initialized as an integer, however, within the input handler, you're re-assigning with a string `init = e.target.value`.  Therefore, you need to convert that string into an integer.

Comment: var init=0;
document.getElementById("intArr").addEventListener('input',function(e){
  init = e.target.value;
  console.log(init);
"console.log(init)" actually returns integer, maybe console.log has some defaults..?

Comment: Do this: `var init=0; document.getElementById("intArr").addEventListener('input',function(e){ init = e.target.value; console.log(typeof init);`

Comment: @iBim'sdaMichi crystal? hehe `:)`